# I'm trying to understand why notifyAll() isn't waking on shared lock

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method that makes one thread wait until another thread calls that method. The context is having the front end wait for the backend to prepare data to be displayed, and then the backend waiting for user input before preparing the next data to be displayed. The problem I'm having here is that both forks in my method call notifyAll() before calling wait() but the notifyAll() doesn't ever trigger the other to catch the exception. Here's a simplified example that causes the problem I'm facing.

```
public class Test {
    static Object lock = new Object();
    static boolean allCaughtUp = false;
    static boolean backCaughtUp = false;
    static boolean frontCaughtUp = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                catchUp("backend");
            }
        }).start();

        catchUp("frontend");
    }

    public static void catchUp(String origin){
        assert origin.equals("frontend") || origin.equals("backend");
        if(origin.equals("frontend")){
            System.out.println("frontend origin reached");
            synchronized (lock){
                while(!allCaughtUp){
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    try{
                        lock.wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println("backend caught up");
                        backCaughtUp = true;
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                    if(backCaughtUp && frontCaughtUp){
                        allCaughtUp = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("backend origin reached");
            synchronized (lock){
                while(!allCaughtUp){
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    try{
                        lock.wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println("frontend caught up");
                        frontCaughtUp = true;
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                    if(backCaughtUp && frontCaughtUp){
                        allCaughtUp = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get before the program gets stuck waiting for itself is:
Frontend origin reached
Backend origin reached

Comment: What do you really want? Serialization of backend/frontend calls? Not very clear.

Comment: Because "[the awakened threads will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll())"

Comment: Are you trying to simulate the [producer-consumer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992862/threads-producer-consumer-in-java)?

Comment: @Abra seems that OP want a "loop" in between front-end/back-end... Not sure.

Comment: I read the documentation too... I guess I don't understand what 'the usual manner' is. Could you explain that in the context of this example? When the first thread is stuck in wait(), what's happening when the next thread calls notifyAll() on the same object?

Comment: I should have been more specific, sorry this is my first post. I am mainly interested what is happening in this example that both threads call notifyAll() before going to wait(), but that never causes them to catch the interrupted exception. The context of this problem should maybe have been a different question. My main concern is learning how notifyAll() and wait() work